# How to correctly create a .gdns to instantiate it?

Tags: c++, godot

I have a gdnative library loaded in my godot. I can also call functions on it, that works. But I want to instantiate c++-Classes from it inside Godot.

I think I have to generate .gdns files for that to work, but i dont really find a example of that.

I created a `.gdns` script already with the `New Script` Dialogue. I named it exactly like the c++ class. And I set the Library in the scripts inspector and set ClassName to `MyClass`. But the following does not work as someClass is `Null`:

```
var someclass = load("res://MyClass.gdns").new();
someclass.method("myMethod");
```

What did I do wrong?
I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/GodotNativeTools/godot-cpp).

Im Using Godot 1.1 and compiled the gdnative-library with the appropriate Godot-cpp headers.

Answer (score 1):

I created a `.gdns` file with the **New Resource** Dialogue and it worked then (after setting the library and Class-name of the `.gdns` in the Inspector).

I'll add more here when I found out why it didn't work before.